# Adding local images in Nuxt 3 into leaflet project

Tags: leaflet, nuxt3

I am experamenting with Nuxt3-Leaflet in an attempt to get a working fictional map. However, I cannot seem to understand how I can use my own local image in my assets folder within the leaflet project.

I have used ImageOverlays and TileLayers, but I beleive I am doing something wrong. Any Advice?